# Generating employees ID with prefix

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and I want to write a code starting with abstract class Employee.java then extend from it other classes (Engineer.java,Technician.java,ServiceManager.java...).The attributes that I have for Employee class are ID, Name, Age, salary.I made the two methods SetSalary() and SetID() abstract.The problem I had is concerning SetID() method, I thought about making ID an array of 6 characters, the first 2 characters are a prefix, for example, the class Engineer has as a prefix the characters from 'A' to 'D', we will start with 'AA0000' then the last 4 characters will get incremented automatically every time I add an Engineer tell the employee with the ID 'AA9999' then the second character should be switched to 'B' , we will have the same process tell the ID 'AD9999' then this time the next employee's ID should be 'BA0000'.The code I have so far for SetID() method:

```
        char[] Mat = new char[6];
        Mat[0]='A';Mat[1]='A';
        Mat[2]='0';Mat[3]='0';Mat[4]='0';Mat[5]='0';

        char[] stop = new char[6] ;
        stop[0]='D';stop[1]='D';stop[2]='9';stop[3]='9';stop[4]='9';stop[5]='9';
        String M = new String(Mat);
        String Sub = M.substring(2,6);

        do {
            if(Mat[2]=='9' && Mat[3]=='9' && Mat[4]=='9' && Mat[5]=='9') {
                if(Mat[1]=='D') {
                    int tmp =(int)Mat[0];
                    ++tmp;
                    Mat[0] = (char)tmp;
                    Mat[1] = 'A';
                    Mat[2]='0';Mat[3]='0';Mat[4]='0';Mat[5]='0';
                }
                else {
                int tmp =(int)Mat[1];
                Mat[1] = (char)++tmp;
                Mat[2]='0';Mat[3]='0';Mat[4]='0';Mat[5]='0';
                }
            }
            else {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(Sub);
                i++;
                if(i<10) { //here
                    char c = Character.forDigit(i, 10);
                    Mat[2]='0';Mat[3]='0';Mat[4]='0';Mat[5]=c;
                }
                if(i<100) { //and here
                    Mat[2]='0';Mat[3]='0';
                    char[] s = ("" + i).toCharArray();
                    Mat[4]=s[0];Mat[5]=s[1];
                }
                if(i<1000) {
                    Mat[2]='0';
                    char[] s = ("" + i).toCharArray();
                    Mat[3]= s[0];Mat[4]=s[1];Mat[5]=s[2];
                }
                else {
                    char[] s = ("" + i).toCharArray();
                    Mat[2]=s[0];Mat[3]=s[1];Mat[4]=s[2];Mat[5]=s[3];
                }
            }
        }
        while(Mat==stop);

        System.out.println(Mat); `
```

It works when it should switch the fist character (try to initialize Mat with 'AD9999'), also to switch the second one(initialize Mat with 'AB9999') but the problem is when it should only increment the number beside the prefix when it is <10 or <100 it doesn't work, in the other two cases (<1000 or >1000) it does the job. I tried to fix the problem in many ways but each time the problem is stacked to those two cases, I hope you could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this alot by using two variables, one being an hex value and the other being an int.  Here is a cut-down test version

```
int firstBit = 0xaa;
int secondBit = 0;

for (int x = 1; x < 20; x++) {

    System.out.printf("%s%d%n", Integer.toHexString(firstBit), x);
    secondBit++;
    if (secondBit > 5) {
        firstBit++;
        secondBit = 0;
    }
    secondBit++;
}
```